# <include> FrameLayout and App/Action Bar Colliding

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have weird problem of colliding

My main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<include
    layout="@layout/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".main.MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Adding `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` this to all fragment layouts solves the problem but why?** I think it is because of include technique that is used in main layout but since toolbar is always there and framelayout is another widget, but it starts calculationg from top of app bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using a `CoordinatorLayout` as parent of your `Fragment` layout.
You haven't any explicit behavior defined there so it will use his default behavior, that's why the `Fragment` layout is "under" your `AppBarLayout`.

A simple way to solve this is to add the `layout_behavior` attribute to `fragment_container`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: Thanks!!. It is first time that i use both framelayout and coordinator layout.  I cannot  accept it as answer yet but sure i will. Have a nice monday syndrome!!